# I am facing an Error while i am scraping YOUTUBE information using Google API

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, scrape

I have list of youtube ids. I wanted to get details about each video such as title, viewcount, likecount, etc. My code was working well until yesterday, suddenly it is throwing an error.

For the experts, initially I have list of video ids. For sample I have used 3 ids. But in actual I have 100+ ids.

```
video_id=['GGHiHodljug','PY8cEyi2MzM','QTCcJipjgxI']
```

Later, I have defined a function to retrieve video information and append it to various list.

```
def get_video_details(youtube, video_id):
    all_video_stats = []
    
    for i in video_ids:
        request = youtube.videos().list(part='snippet,statistics',id=video_id)
        response = request.execute()
        
        for video in response['items']:
            video_stats = dict(Title = video['snippet']['title'],
                               Published_date = video['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                               Views = video['statistics']['viewCount'],
                               Likes = video['statistics']['likeCount'],
                               #Dislikes = video['statistics']['dislikeCount'],
                               Comments = video['statistics']['commentCount']
                               #Shares = video['statistics']['']
                               )
            all_video_stats.append(video_stats)
    

return all_video_stats
```

Now, I tried to call upon the function. But it throws an error, which i never faced till yesterday.

```
video_details = get_video_details(youtube,video_id)
```

The error that was received is shown below.

> HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatistics&id=kwlJUFUJeBU&id=9qjgV9UynUU&id=9BRNhfz9TZU&id=Cm614VNaapI&id=Gk0O1hBZL1g&id=QuIfcSDxEZY&id=lO48EoPn7-A&id=n1S886NBQYA&id=y4DGkrs7KcM&id=vk3ahhtY5qE&id=Zr3cAIU6bZM&id=fLC_LfstdAA&id=s4aneR0tc1s&id=A0FJpd-lieI&id=7fFFfU6Cgmk&id=4VJSE59j1pM&id=ns51Rp7o_Bw&id=LQrMIBpGrbA&id=XOeTeM-1qKc&id=f6Ms318wTj0&id=etfoGZquiSA&id=a1LUlovdL_A&id=nTTBa4-0Z7I&id=6KOYprSy1KA&id=wjPmweQ4peQ&id=Cw0xY42b_Mo&id=-n_mVFPzeuY&id=R8ZNqKerC1o&id=JnZhAPBfPYw&id=8o2yLPDr_d8&id=DOoE4hPiJuw&id=M4HRJXRZZAM&id=cNedzwOOqag&id=Qqj96rMBxTE&id=_0J7VcMtKkQ&id=kZ8ObOkzq4w&id=6P_wnhUb02g&id=kH5UPfi3cFQ&id=qtDl9Yu8or0&id=Xzn-URGHItA&id=xutJ2uQ4tT0&id=bZ71zj8BunU&id=gHtjvLejc6E&id=92pTgb_7QI4&id=KKZkES9gfuE&id=Qj01vTif2yI&id=Qkc1A8cJEmw&id=whBSkar_rCs&id=wOPEC95vVUs&id=pi3Tm9lzvLU&id=Ip-PimAxgjw&id=r1W13UnMwLU&id=z68p5nBZ03k&id=6wMuvqUkgqY&id=b7AYFCw8cQA&id=nMrEiom0S74&id=-bGqNqT8Ckg&id=CSXPZuNVqGw&id=wP09CGKyDdg&id=eY_fPjwZ3hU&id=nT9mgg7BtH4&id=D2SqeQPr38I&id=h-0ELP6rNhQ&id=33OOngFBcnk&id=ojbMrcTlQ_s&id=Kt6xncrWZUQ&id=xUCWiEhCIgI&id=jDEC_sV67B4&id=Dxw9xEpkeYk&id=tFiAsk_sOC0&id=eLLXCtd187I&id=3y499rX5A8Q&id=keTSJlzVu2I&id=RtnXrhDxpgo&id=VmbouDaMoM4&id=NWBNOA_fwcA&id=7mTnG30Y8c8&id=gOM5A0w8V1s&id=rLEDXBhuspk&id=XQ-NNWBySIo&id=_klVNQEzauU&id=ukNGhEZLEhw&id=eI8quor4HmM&id=DLbfMGozcyM&id=GZBAUuUbCFs&id=qwquUC4Wk0s&id=aEsEnJMiRqU&id=EKPQX6LC4Uw&id=HmAn0BgKGhA&id=0jlFNP8nDzs&id=n3iSKVMfbFw&id=Ypaah0zPWIo&id=oyOHOcyp2T8&id=aLmJ5zXsVtk&id=dEsEaJGYAZM&id=KGe7nId4GGs&id=BoRgRqqeiw8&id=GGHiHodljug&id=PY8cEyi2MzM&id=QTCcJipjgxI&key=AIzaSyDpPBFs9LZ-33rVUeSKyHCaz5E0UmWmZXk&alt=json
> returned "The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.".
> Details: "[{'message': 'The request specifies an invalid filter
> parameter.', 'domain': 'youtube.parameter', 'reason':
> 'invalidFilters', 'location': 'parameters.', 'locationType':
> 'other'}]">

Answer (score 2):

For pass more than one video_id, *the elements are separated by comma*.

Instead of:

```
&id=f6Ms318wTj0&id=etfoGZquiSA&id=a1LUlovdL_A
```

use:

```
&id=f6Ms318wTj0,etfoGZquiSA,a1LUlovdL_A
```

Answer (score 0):

The API endpoint does not accept more than 50 IDs.  So if we have more then 50 ids, information about each video can be obtained using a loop.

Comment: Could you maybe link the docs on this?

Comment: @vigneshwaran the limit 50 is for `maxResults`, not ids